# Execute function when two array data points match

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, google-apps-script

I am new to JavaScript so please forgive any errors/obvious oversights.

I am trying to find a way to run a function that only executes when one of the `"Run months"` matches the current month. The code underneath seems to make sense to me but doesn't execute?

For a bit of context I am trying to run a time based Macro is Google-Sheets that only executes once a quarter (`Runmonths`).

```html
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {

var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
var RunMonths = ["January", "April", "July", "October"];
var now = new Date();
var thisMonth = months[now.getMonth()];
var getMonth = Runmonths[now.getMonth()];


  if(thisMonth === getMonth){
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    spreadsheet.getRange('AE:AE').activate();
    spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
    spreadsheet.getRange('AE1').activate();
    spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('OUTCOME');

  }
}
```

Comment: what you are getting in now.getMonth() ?

Comment: Maybe because of the typo: `RunMonths` instead of `Runmonths` on the line: `var getMonth = Runmonths[now.getMonth()];`

Comment: @NishantDixit I have tried console.log(getMonth) but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: If this method actually creates time driven triggers, make sure you don't over-create them (you can only see your own, even via script). If it doesn't, then you need a better name for your function.

Answer (score 1):

`Runmonths` only contains 4 elements, but the `now.getMonth()` is returning a value of 6, which is out of range. Instead, check if `thisMonth` is in the `Runmonths` array. You can do this in Google Apps Script using the [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method.

I've removed some of the logic from your original code to address your specific question. You can play with the date in `now` to see that this will execute the months you want it to.

```
function test() {
  var months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
  var RunMonths = ["January", "April", "July", "October"];
  var now = new Date("February 1, 2018");
  var thisMonth = months[now.getMonth()];
  Logger.log("This month: " + thisMonth); 
  if (RunMonths.indexOf(thisMonth) != -1) {
    Logger.log("Run this month");
  } else {
    Logger.log("Don't run this month");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `getMonth()` returns an integer. You are using this returned integer as an index.

The two arrays you are using are not holding the same value at a certain index.
`months[1]` is `'February'` and `RunMonths[1]` is `"April"`.

And since `"February"` is not equal to `"April"` you are not getting to the other functions.